# How to disable close button of dialog box in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Option Compare Database    

Dim pUser As String

Private Sub signinCmd_Click()    
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

Dim idEntered As String
Dim pwEntered As String

idEntered = Me.idBox & ""
pwEntered = Me.pwBox & ""

pUser = idEntered

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset ("SELECT * " & vbCrLf & _
    "From userInfo " & vbCrLf & "WHERE [ID] = '" Me.idBox & "'")

    If pwEntered = rst.Fields("Password") & "" Then
        Call getPermission(idEntered)
    Else
        MsgBox "You typed the wrong password. Try Again.", vbExclamation, "Security"
    End If
End Sub





Sub getPermission(pStr As String)
  Select Case pStr
    Case "Guest"
        SetEnabledState(False)
        DoCmd.LockNavigationPane(True)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Startup", acNormal, , , , acDialog
    Case "Manager"
        DoCmd.LockNavigationPane(True)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Startup", acNormal, , , , acDialog
    Case "Administrator"
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Startup", acNormal, , , , acDialog
 End Select
End Sub




Private Declare Function GetSystemMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal bRevert As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function EnableMenuItem Lib "user32" (byVal hMenu As _
Long, ByVal wIdEnableItem As Long, ByVal wEnable As Long) As Long

Const MF_GRAYED = &H1&
Const MF_BYCOMMAND = &H0&
Const SC_CLOSE = &HF060&

Public Function SetEnabledState(bInState As Boolean)
    Call CloseButtonState(bInState)
    Call ExitMenuState(bInState)
End Function

Sub ExitMenuState(bInExitState As Boolean)
    Application.CommandBars("File").Controls("Exit").Enabled = bInExitState
End Sub

Sub CloseButtonState(boolClose As Boolean)
    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim wFlags As Long
    Dim hMenu As Long
    Dim result As Long

    hwnd = Application.hWndAccessApp
    hMenu = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, 0)
    If Not boolClose Then
        wFlags = MF_BYCOMMAND Or MF_GRAYED
    Else
        wFlags = MF_BYCOMMAND And Not MF_GRAYED
    End If

    result = EnableMenuItem(hMenu, SC_CLOSE, wFlags)
End Sub
```

I am trying to disable just the close button of dialog box when the "guest" has logged in, but when I run this code, not the close button of the box but that of MS Access is being disabled. How can I solve this problem in code-wise? (SetEnabledState Function is which decides to disable or enable the close button with its Boolean parameter.)

Comment: Which dialog box? Btw, do you know what this line `hwnd = Application.hWndAccessApp` does?

Comment: I mean the dialog box that comes up by getPermission Function. (DoCmd.OpenForm "Startup", acNormal, , , , acDialog)

Comment: And actually I don't know well about what hwnd = Application.hWndAccessApp does. @SiddharthRout

Comment: The answer lies in the 2nd question of my first comment ;)

Comment: Ah.. I guess it will gonna work if I change hWndAccessApp with some value dealing with dialog box???

Comment: `some value dealing with dialog box` That some value is called the `Handle` of the dialog box. Like you and me, we both have names, similarly windows have `“handles” (hWnd)`, Class etc. Once you know what that `hWnd` is, it is easier to interact with that window.

Comment: I don't work with access much else I would have told you how to retrieve the handle of that form. I know how to do it with Excel's/Word's/Powerpoint's/vb6/vb.net Userform's/Form's though

Comment: Thanks anyway! I think I have to look into what handle means and what kind of handle is dealing with the dialog box.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an annoying work around You would also have to make the form a pop up or modal as this will not work with acDialog although I am not sure you need a Dialog anyway.

Modal = Holds focus until closed

PopUp = Remains on top but does not require focus until closed

Dialog = pause further code in current Sub or function until Form Close and then resume.

since you are using a Dialog you are actually unnecessarily stopping the code in the middle of the case statement even though there is really no execution after form closes.

```
Sub getPermission(pStr As String)
  Select Case pStr
    Case "Guest"
        DoCmd.LockNavigationPane(True)
        DoCmd.Close
        SetEnabledStateAndOpen "Startup", False
    Case "Manager"
        DoCmd.LockNavigationPane(True)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Startup", acNormal, , , , acDialog
    Case "Administrator"
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Startup", acNormal, , , , acDialog
  End Select
End Sub


Sub SetEnabledStateAndOpen(frm As String,closeState As Boolean)
   'Change Close Button at runtime by opening in design view altering closebutton and then switching views
        DoCmd.OpenForm frm, acDesign
        Forms(frm).CloseButton = closeState
        Forms(frm).SetFocus
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFormView
End Sub
```

**Additional Note**

Not sure what this application is for but the query is highly injectable try entering `' OR 'a' = 'a` into `Me.idBox` and see what happens becuase it will generate a query the looks like this `SELECT * From userInfo WHERE [ID] = '' OR 'a' = 'a'` Which return all records in the userInfo table which may not have a large effect due to the password check but when this query returns 0 results you will hit an issue with something like `Administrator' AND 'a' = 'b` generates

`SELECT * From userInfo WHERE [ID] = 'Administrator' AND 'a' = 'b'` which turns into

```
If "" =  "" Then
    Call getPermission('Administrator')
Else
    MsgBox "You typed the wrong password. Try Again.", vbExclamation, "Security"
End If
```

If it doesn't throw an invalid use of null error